# Unknown column in jackets in field list

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been trying to add values to a table named bill_items and this is the coding for the button "add to cart" but it shows and error saying "Unknown column Jacket in field list. What is wrong in this coding?

```
try {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from mens_wear where Item_code = 1090;");
    while(rs.next()){
        icode = rs.getInt("Item_code");
        p = rs.getInt("Price");
        bname = rs.getString("Brand_Name");
        iname = rs.getString("Item_Name");
        t = rs.getString("Type");
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    con.close();
} catch(Exception e)
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());}
    try {
        Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/aashita","root","1510");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        int a = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into bill_items values('"+icode+"','"+t+"','"+bname+"','"+iname+"','"+p+"');");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Added Successfully");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to your indentation and do not precursor your code with an `>`. As an aside: you may want to take a look at the [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Of course it did not. It is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practice to not specify column names in an insert and depend on table column order. There could also be an issue with escaping of your query string if any of your values contain quotes. I would try adding the column names and using a prepared statement with parameters.

```
string updateText = "insert into bill_items (Item_code, Type, Brand_Name, Item_Name, Price) ";
updateText += "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(updateText);
stmt.setInt(1, icode);
stmt.setString(2, t);
stmt.setString(3, bname);
stmt.setString(4, iname);
stmt.setInt(5, p);

int a = stmt.executeUpdate();
```